# how to add image as icon in DrawerItem in react native v5 (0.62)?

Tags: javascript, react-native

i am working on react native 0.62 project in which i have created custom drawer. Image is properly added to DrawerItemList but not working with DrawerItem. i have tried in many ways but no solution. i got stucked in this issue for 2 days.

```
MainNavigator.js
<Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Dashboard" drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />} hideStatusBar={false} focused={true} labelStyle={{ fontSize: 14, fontFamily: 'OpenSans-SemiBold' }} drawerContentOptions={{ activeBackgroundColor: "#F1F1F1", activeTintColor: "#000000", inactiveTintColor: "#818181" }}>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Dashboard" component={DashboardStackScreen} options={{
        drawerIcon: ({ focused, size }) => (
          <Image source={require('../assets/images/dashboard.png')} style={{ height: 17.78, width: 16}}  resizeMode="contain"/>
        ),
      }}
      />
  <Drawer.Screen name="LMS" component={LmsStackScreen} options={{
        drawerIcon: ({ focused, size }) => (
          <Image source={require('../assets/images/lms.png')} style={{ height: 14.46, width: 16 }}  resizeMode="contain"/>
        ),
      }} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Change Password" component={LmsStackScreen} options={{
        drawerIcon: ({ focused, size }) => (
          <Image source={require('../assets/images/key.png')} style={{ height: 8.73, width: 16 }}  resizeMode="contain"/>
        ),
      }} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>


DrawerContent.js

  <View style={{flex:5}}>
                        <DrawerContentScrollView {...props} >
                            <DrawerItemList {...props} />
                            <DrawerItem     
                            labelStyle={{ fontSize: 14, fontFamily: 'OpenSans-SemiBold' }}     activeBackgroundColor= "#F1F1F1" activeTintColor="#000000" inactiveTintColor= "#818181"
                          /*   options={{
                            drawerIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => (
                                <Icon
                                  name="home"
                                  style={{color: color, fontSize: size}}
                                />
                              )}} */
                            /*  options={{  */
                                 /* drawerIcon={ ({ focused, size }) => {
                                  <Image source={require('../assets/images/logout.png')} style={{ height: 15, width: 15 }} resizeMode="contain"/>
                                   size={size}}} */  /* }}  */
                            /*   }}    */                   
                                label="Logout"
                                icon={({ focused, color, size })=>{
                                    <Image source={require('../assets/images/logout.png')} style={{ height: size, width: size }} resizeMode="contain"/>
                                 }}   
                                onPress={() => console.log('Logout')}
                            />
                    
                        </DrawerContentScrollView>
                        </View>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is really simple
You are using curly braces so it wont return the image until you return it.

you can change the code like below

```
icon={({ focused, color, size }) => (
  <Image
    source={{ uri: 'https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png' }}
    style={{ height: size, width: size }}
    resizeMode="contain"
  />
)}
```

Or simply put a return like below

```
  icon={({ focused, color, size }) => {
          return (
            <Image
              source={{ uri: 'https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png' }}
              style={{ height: size, width: size }}
              resizeMode="contain"
            />
          );
        }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much... it was a silly mistake. Thank you for your quick answer.

Comment: i need one more help. For each component of the drawer, i have created header with gradient background linear but the main content of the content of the component is hiding behind the header.. if i remove gradient background color then it doesn't hide.

Comment: Got any code that i can look into? i've never tried that actually

Comment: const DashboardStack = createStackNavigator(); const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator(); const GradientHeader = props => (<View style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}><LinearGradient colors={['#6CCFF6', '#596AB2']} start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }} end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }} style={{  height: 128 }} > <Header {...props} /> </LinearGradient> </View> )

Comment: const DashboardStackScreen = ({ navigation }) => { return ( DashboardStack.Navigator screenOptions={{  headerTitle: 'Good Morning, John',  header: props => <GradientHeader {...props} />,  headerLeft: () => ( <TouchableOpacity onPress={navigation.openDrawer} style={{padding: 20}}>

Comment: <Image source={require('../assets/images/menu_bar.png')} style={{width:18, height:12}}/> </TouchableOpacity> ), headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent', },headerTintColor: '#fff', headerTitleStyle: { fontFamily: 'OpenSans-SemiBold', fontSize: 20}, }}> <DashboardStack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} /> </DashboardStack.Navigator> );}

Comment: I cant figure out the issue here as i havent worked with linear gradient , can you raise another question so someone with experience can help you, really sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217597/discussion-between-priyanka-gupta-and-guruparan-giritharan).